# Filter select categories based on selected main categories (angularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm wondering if it's possible to filter categories selector based on the first selected category in my current code and how to achieve desired effect.

This is my controller which provides all categories

```
controllers.addItemCtrl = function($scope, productsFactory, sessionFactory, categoriesFactory, $http, $location){
    sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
        var loggedIn = data.logged_in;
        if(loggedIn){
            categoriesFactory.getCategoriesList().success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.categories = data;
            });
        } else {
            window.location.href="/#/login";
        }
    });
}
```

This is my response for categories

```
[{"id_category":"1","category":"Audio, video & photo","parent":"0","alias":"audio-video-and-photo","image":"" ....etc}]
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">
        <i class="icon-user"></i><b>Category</b>
    </label><br>

    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option ng-repeat="c in categories track by $index" 
                ng-if="c.parent == 0" 
                value="{{c.id_category}}">{{c.category}}</option>
    </select>

    <span ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : errorDescription}" 
          ng-bind="errorDescription">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="subCategory">
        <i class="icon-user"></i><b>Sub category</b>
    </label><br>

    <select name="subCategory" id="subCategory">
        <option ng-repeat="c in categories track by $index" 
                ng-if="c.parent > 0" value="{{c.id_category}}">
            {{c.category}}
        </option>
    </select>

    <span ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : errorDescription}" 
          ng-bind="errorDescription"></span>
</div>
```

How to make a filter, Let say if I select main category Audio, video & photo with id 1, then I want in another selector show only categories with parent id 1

If you need any additional information, please let me know and I will provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category"><i class="icon-user"></i><b>Category</b></label><br>

          <select name="category" id="category" ng-change='searchSubCategory(parentCat)' ng-model='parentCat'>
            <option ng-repeat="c in categories track by $index" ng-if="c.parent == 0" value="{{c.id_category}}">
              {{c.category}}
            </option>
          </select>

          <span ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : errorDescription}" ng-bind="errorDescription"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subCategory"><i class="icon-user"></i><b>Sub category</b></label><br>

          <select name="subCategory" id="subCategory">
            <option ng-repeat="c in subcategory track by $index" ng-if="c.parent > 0" value="{{c.id_category}}">
            {{c.category}}
            </option>
          </select>

          <span ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : errorDescription}" ng-bind="errorDescription"></span>
        </div>

      </div>
```

### Javascript Logic

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.categories = [{"id_category":"1","category":"Audio, video & photo","parent":"0","alias":"audio-video-and-photo","image":""},{"id_category":"2","category":"Music players","parent":"1","alias":"music-players","image":""},{"id_category":"3","category":"Musical instruments","parent":"1","alias":"musical-instruments","image":""},{"id_category":"4","category":"Music accessories","parent":"1","alias":"music-accessories","image":""},{"id_category":"5","category":"Hi-Fi","parent":"1","alias":"hi-fi","image":""},{"id_category":"6","category":"Home cinema","parent":"1","alias":"home-cinema","image":""},{"id_category":"7","category":"TV's","parent":"1","alias":"tv","image":""},{"id_category":"8","category":"Rest","parent":"1","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"9","category":"Cars & bikes","parent":"0","alias":"cars-and-bikes","image":""},{"id_category":"10","category":"Whole cars","parent":"9","alias":"whole-cars","image":""},{"id_category":"11","category":"Bikes","parent":"9","alias":"bikes","image":""},{"id_category":"12","category":"Car parts","parent":"9","alias":"car-parts","image":""},{"id_category":"13","category":"Auto acoustics","parent":"9","alias":"auto-acoustics","image":""},{"id_category":"14","category":"Mobile homes, trailers and equipment","parent":"9","alias":"mobile-homes-trailers-and-equipment","image":""},{"id_category":"15","category":"Tires","parent":"9","alias":"tires","image":""},{"id_category":"16","category":"Rims","parent":"9","alias":"rims","image":""},{"id_category":"17","category":"Car accessories","parent":"9","alias":"car-accessories","image":""},{"id_category":"18","category":"Home and garden","parent":"0","alias":"home-and-garden","image":""},{"id_category":"19","category":"Construction and installation","parent":"18","alias":"construction-and-installation","image":""},{"id_category":"20","category":"Refrigerators & Freezers","parent":"18","alias":"refrigerators-and-freezers","image":""},{"id_category":"21","category":"Cooking and kitchen utensils","parent":"18","alias":"cooking-and-kitchen-utensils","image":""},{"id_category":"22","category":"Home equipment","parent":"18","alias":"home-equipment","image":""},{"id_category":"23","category":"Tools and machines","parent":"18","alias":"tools-and-machines","image":""},{"id_category":"24","category":"furniture","parent":"18","alias":"furniture","image":""},{"id_category":"25","category":"cleaning and washing machines","parent":"18","alias":"cleaning-and-washing-machines","image":""},{"id_category":"26","category":"Garden and working equipment","parent":"18","alias":"garden-and-working-equipment","image":""},{"id_category":"27","category":"Pets and accessories","parent":"18","alias":"pets-and-accessories","image":""},{"id_category":"28","category":"Camera","parent":"1","alias":"camera","image":""},{"id_category":"29","category":"Beauty and health","parent":"0","alias":"0","image":""},{"id_category":"30","category":"Personal care appliances","parent":"29","alias":"personal-care-appliances","image":""},{"id_category":"31","category":"Appliances for health","parent":"29","alias":"appliances-for-health","image":""},{"id_category":"32","category":"Cosmetics and hygiene","parent":"29","alias":"cosmetics-and-hygiene","image":""},{"id_category":"33","category":"Makeup","parent":"29","alias":"makeup","image":""},{"id_category":"34","category":"Jewellery","parent":"29","alias":"jewellery","image":""},{"id_category":"35","category":"Glasses","parent":"29","alias":"glasses","image":""},{"id_category":"36","category":"Perfumes","parent":"29","alias":"perfumes","image":""},{"id_category":"37","category":"Rest","parent":"18","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"38","category":"Rest","parent":"9","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"39","category":"Hand watches","parent":"29","alias":"hand-watches","image":""},{"id_category":"40","category":"Clothing","parent":"0","alias":"clothing","image":""},{"id_category":"41","category":"Women's clothing","parent":"40","alias":"womens-clothing","image":""},{"id_category":"42","category":"Men's clothing","parent":"40","alias":"mens-clothing","image":""},{"id_category":"43","category":"Kid's clothing","parent":"40","alias":"kids-clothing","image":""},{"id_category":"44","category":"Fashion accessories","parent":"40","alias":"fashion-accessories","image":""},{"id_category":"45","category":"Rest","parent":"40","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"46","category":"Books and literature","parent":"82","alias":"books-and-literature","image":""},{"id_category":"47","category":"Office equipment","parent":"82","alias":"office-equipment","image":""},{"id_category":"48","category":"Office Furniture","parent":"82","alias":"office-furniture","image":""},{"id_category":"49","category":"School","parent":"82","alias":"school","image":""},{"id_category":"50","category":"Rest","parent":"82","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"51","category":"Computers","parent":"0","alias":"computers","image":""},{"id_category":"52","category":"Laptops","parent":"51","alias":"laptops","image":""},{"id_category":"53","category":"Stationary computer","parent":"51","alias":"stationary-computer","image":""},{"id_category":"54","category":"Tablets","parent":"51","alias":"tablets","image":""},{"id_category":"55","category":"Computer components","parent":"51","alias":"computer-components","image":""},{"id_category":"56","category":"Computer equipment","parent":"51","alias":"computer-equipment","image":""},{"id_category":"57","category":"Network","parent":"51","alias":"network","image":""},{"id_category":"58","category":"Printers & scanners","parent":"51","alias":"printers-and-scanners","image":""},{"id_category":"59","category":"Cartridges and toners","parent":"51","alias":"cartridges-and-toners","image":""},{"id_category":"60","category":"Rest","parent":"51","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"61","category":"Sport","parent":"0","alias":"sport","image":""},{"id_category":"62","category":"Outdoor & camping","parent":"61","alias":"outdoor-and-camping","image":""},{"id_category":"63","category":"Modelling","parent":"61","alias":"modelling","image":""},{"id_category":"64","category":"Racquet Sports","parent":"61","alias":"racquet-sports","image":""},{"id_category":"65","category":"Cycling","parent":"61","alias":"cycling","image":""},{"id_category":"66","category":"Fitness & aerobics","parent":"61","alias":"Fitness-and-aerobics","image":""},{"id_category":"67","category":"Hiking & climbing","parent":"61","alias":"Hiking-and-climbing","image":""},{"id_category":"68","category":"Skiing","parent":"61","alias":"skiing","image":""},{"id_category":"69","category":"GPS, watches and gauges","parent":"61","alias":"Gps-watches-and-gauges","image":""},{"id_category":"70","category":"Rest","parent":"61","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"71","category":"Phones","parent":"0","alias":"phones","image":""},{"id_category":"72","category":"Gsm","parent":"71","alias":"gsm","image":""},{"id_category":"73","category":"Gsm accessories","parent":"71","alias":"gsm-accessories","image":""},{"id_category":"74","category":"Rest","parent":"71","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"75","category":"Kids","parent":"0","alias":"kids","image":""},{"id_category":"76","category":"Car seats","parent":"75","alias":"car-seats","image":""},{"id_category":"77","category":"Prams","parent":"75","alias":"prams","image":""},{"id_category":"78","category":"Baby equipment and accessories","parent":"75","alias":"Baby-equipment-and-accessories","image":""},{"id_category":"79","category":"Toys","parent":"75","alias":"toys","image":""},{"id_category":"80","category":"Children's playgrounds","parent":"75","alias":"childrens-playground","image":""},{"id_category":"81","category":"Rest","parent":"29","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"82","category":"Books & Office material","parent":"0","alias":"books-and-office-material","image":""},{"id_category":"83","category":"Rest","parent":"75","alias":"rest","image":""},{"id_category":"84","category":"Bike accessories","parent":"9","alias":"bike-accessories","image":""}];

    $scope.searchSubCategory = function(parentCat)
    {   
        $scope.subcategory = [];
        for(i=0;i<$scope.categories.length;i++)
        {   
            if(parentCat==$scope.categories[i].parent)
            {
                $scope.subcategory.push($scope.categories[i])
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Create simple function when selected index change and do some little logic